# How to findone by patientId and insert multiple data at once in medicine

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below is schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PatientFluidSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    patient: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Pateint",
      required: true,
    },
    medicine: [
      {
        medicinename: {
          type: String,
     
        },
        fluidquantity: {
          type: String,
          
        },
        fluidtakentime: {
          type: String,
          
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("PateintFluid", PatientFluidSchema);
```

I am new to nodejs and i am stuck on this problem. How to findOne with patientId and insert multiple value in medicine using insertMany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add one object into the `medicine` array you can use `findOneAndUpdate` with the `$push` operator like so:

```
const patientId = req.body.patientId;
const update = await PatientFluidModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        patient: patientId,
    },
    {
        $push: {
            "medicine": {
               medicinename: 'A', 
               fluidquantity: 'B', 
               fluidtakentime: 'C'
            }
        }
    }, {new: true});
```

Or if you want to add multiple objects you can use a combination of `$push` with `$each` like so:

```
const object1 = {medicinename: 'A', fluidquantity: 'B',fluidtakentime: 'C'};
const object2 = {medicinename: 'D', fluidquantity: 'E',fluidtakentime: 'F'};
const object3 = {medicinename: 'X', fluidquantity: 'Y',fluidtakentime: 'Z'};
const patientId = req.body.patientId;
const update = await PatientFluidModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        patient: patientId,
    },
    {
        $push: {
            "medicine": {
               $each: [object1, object2, object3]
            }
        }
    }, {new: true});
```

You can find out more from offical docs on [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as well as [$each](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/each/).

**Edit**: To help with your issue of uploading multiple medicines you could do this inside your `AddDailymedicine` function:

```js
const medecines = [];
for(let i =0; i < req.body.medicinename.length; i++){
  medecines.push({
    medicinename: req.body.medicinename[i],
    fluidquantity: req.body.fluidquantity[i], 
    fluidtakentime: req.body.fluidtakentime[i],
  });
}
```

This will create multiple objects in the `medecines` locally scoped array. Then just use spread sytax in your `$each` like so:

```js
   $each: [...medecines]
```

Comment: @jQuenny I am  able to get Id only data is not inserting into MongoDB database : const AddDailymedicine = async (req, res) =>{

    const {medicinename,fluidquantity,fluidtakentime} = req.body;
  
    const newfluid = await patientfluidModel.findOneAndUpdate({
      patient:req.params.userId
    },{
        $push:{
            fluids: { $each:[{medicinename:medicinename,
                fluidquantity:fluidquantity,
                fluidtakentime:fluidtakentime}]}
             
            
        }
    },{new:true})
    console.log(newfluid)

}

Comment: It looks liike you are trying to push to `fluids` but your schema suggests you should push to `medicine`. Have you changed your schema from the one above? You also only need to use `$each` if you are pushing more than one object. Just a reminder.

Comment: above schema is correct. I am trying to upload multiple medicines at one time when user press upload button. even using each I am getting id for each medicine but value like medicinename,timetaken,quantity is not updated in collection but if I do each medicine at one I get value in collection.

Comment: Your query is pushing the objects into the `fluids` array. Your schema only has a `medicine` array. You need to push to the `medicine` array.

Comment: I have already changed fluids to medicine it was typo error, but issue is same.

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware `const {medicinename,fluidquantity,fluidtakentime} = req.body;` destructures the `req.body` object so if `req.body` = `{medicinename: 'A', fluidquantity: 'B',fluidtakentime: 'C'}` then that is one object. If your users are adding multiple medicines then `req.body` might = `{medicinename:['A', 'X'], fluidquantity: ['B', 'Y'],fluidtakentime: ['C', 'Z']}` so you need to handle object destructre differently. Do a `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: still the problem is same

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body)` and I may be able to help you.

Comment: this is the result i get when I do console.log(req.body) [
  { fluidname: 'milk', fluidquantity: '120', fluidtakentime: '1' },
  { fluidname: 'juice', fluidquantity: '220', fluidtakentime: '10' }
]

Comment: OK thank you. Now I see. Just do `$each: [...req.body]`.

Comment: You also won't need to do the initial object destructure i.e `const {medicinename,fluidquantity,fluidtakentime} = req.body;` is no longer required.

Comment: Thankyou JQueeny for your help. Now it's working.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project.